# name conflict in renaming multiple files in wdired mode

Tags: file, emacs, rename, dired

In wdired mode, if I try to rename file `A` to `B`, and file `B` to `C` in one step, the part of changing of `A` to `B` may be rejected because it conflicts with the existing file `B`, and only `B` to `C` will be done. But that actually depends on the order; if `B` to `C` is done earlier, it should not cause a problem. Is there an easy way to let wdired look for such smart ordering of operations and let it do `A` to `B` and `B` to `C` in one step? Some additions to wdired, alternative to wdired, or some hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: I thought at first that "Improved renaming order" at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WDired#toc4 looked like a solution, but the following comment suggests that this has been taken care of in the standard code, so I guess it doesn't cover your situation.

edit 2: Which version of Emacs are you using?

After looking again at the description for that obsolete patch, and then doing some testing in Emacs 23.2.1, it seems pretty smart about this sort of thing, and I got the message "Circular renaming: using temporary file name" when duplicates would be generated, and the end result was correct.

Comment: I am using gnu emacs 23.3.1, but the problem arises. Is it possible that my wdired is old?

Comment: If you're not using the wdired that ships with Emacs (it's been part of Emacs since 22.1 according to the Wiki), then yes, that's definitely possible! `M-x find-libraray RET wdired RET` will take you to the file. If it is in site-lisp or some other local directory, you'll undoubtedly want to get rid of it. FWIW, mine has a "Version: 2.0" comment near the top (Emacs 23.2)

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that I had wdired in my local directory, and it has been there for a long while. I removed it, and it works now.